# Why did Walter White decide to become a teacher after Gray Matter?

Tags: breaking-bad

If anything that I have learned from Walter White's character in *Breaking Bad*, it is his love for lab and chemistry. After leaving Gray Matter, why didn't he continue his research, or decide to start his own business, as he was a genius chemist that anyone has ever seen?

Becoming a school teacher doesn't suit his type and was a waste of his talent. Starting from the very first episode we see that he is poor (before his cancer is diagnosed). Why didn't he think about his family before, leaving them with money etc.?